# How to get number of selected options using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a multiple selection list which have more than 5 options. But i want to restrict the selection of the options to 2 or 3 options. How to do it using jquery? How to get the count of selection options in multiple selection list? I am using jquery validation plugin.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use [the `:selected` selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) to select them, then get the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/), like this:

```
var count = $("#mySelect :selected").length;
```

Comment: First is better, since `$("#mySelect").val()` is null if no option is selected.

Comment: @svinto - good catch, I override `.val()` to return an empty array in that case in my build, IMO it *should* do that by default..it's proven more useful for me, but we'll see if it ever changes.

Comment: Ya, First is better and gave correct result for my situation. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the number of selected items in the multiselect with the following:

```
$('#selectList :selected').length
```

Where #selectList is the id of your .

Comment: `.count()` isn't a jQuery function :) `.size()` is, but it's just a wrapper for `.length`, might as well use it directly.

Answer (score 3):

`var n = $("input:checked").length;`
see this for more detail:
http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP had in mind, but more importantly it'll match every `<input>` including radio buttons, so be careful when using `:checked` alone.

Answer (score 1):

For checkboxes I'm using:

```
$('input[name="InputName"]:checked').size()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use select2 for multi select
and this worked with me

```
 $("#selectedItems").val().length;
```

note that 'selectedItems' is the id of multiselect list