# selectedOptions.length not working in Internet explorer but works properly in chrome and firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working with `ui.multiselect.js` which is just similar to HTML Select:

I wanted the length of the selected elements. So i had used the below code:

```
var selectedOption =  document.getElementById('animalList').selectedOptions.length;
```

But it seems `selectedOptions.length` is not working in IE but working properly in Chrome and Firefox

Below are the alternatives i have already tried:

```
var select = document.getElementById('animalList');
var len = select.options.length;
```

I get the result as 0.

```
$("#animalList :selected").length;
```

I get the result as 0.

Comment: So is the ID "mySelect" or "animalList"?

Comment: Show your HTML.

Comment: Could you supply an example of this using `[<>]` to insert a runnable code block into your question please ?

Comment: @ShijinTR why you changed the `id`? You could add an answer instead.

Comment: @Azim He find that method from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707812/how-to-get-number-of-selected-options-using-jquery

Comment: I added a solution which demonstrates how to make it work properly when using javascript or jquery.  If it still doesn't work, then you know something somewhere else in your code is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the count of a `select` element using `multiselect`, make sure your code looks like the following :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('button').click(function() {
    // jquery version
    var count = $("#foo :selected").length;
    console.log("jQuery Count: " + count);
    
    // pure javascript version
    var options = document.getElementById('foo').options, count = 0;
    for (var i=0; i < options.length; i++) {
       if (options[i].selected) count++;
    }
    console.log("Pure Javascript: " + count);
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Count Selected</button><br>
<select multiple id="foo">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I have included both a pure javascript version and jQuery version which are executed when you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the length using the following method

```
  var len = 0;
  if($("#animalList").val()!=null){
   len = $("#animalList").val().length;
  }
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ar2Ra/13/)**